# Read from XML write another XML

Tags: c#, xml

I want to do a software who read something from xml and write another thing in other xml, example:
From here I want the software to read all values between <>[value]

```
<quest>
 <id>1</id>
 <reward_exp1>1848</reward_exp1>
 <reward_gold1>560</reward_gold1>
</quest>
```

And write something else like this

```
<quest id="1"><reward gold="560" exp="184" /></quest>
```

Can I find a tutorial or something?

Comment: Yes, you can find a tutorial or something, try and do a bit of research before you ask questions on here.

Comment: Have you looked for a tutorial? have you Googled for reading and writing XML with .NET? Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: The answer to your question `Can I find a tutorial or something?` is yes, you can find a tutorial and something. You could use a search engine. For example http://google.com is quite a popular one. Have you tried using it? Is there something else you would like to ask?

Comment: @Daniel You might want to have a read of the FAQ http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: @DanielLaurovici welcome to SO. There is no out-of the box tutorial for this purpose. However you can try to read about `XDocument`, XML Serialization or `XmlDocument` subjects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do this would be to use linq to xml.

Here are some links to get you started.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387044.aspx
http://www.dreamincode.net/forums/topic/218979-linq-to-xml/

There are other options e.g. xslt transform, xml dom

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking to do is called XML Transformation, it's a common problem with many different ways to approach a solution.

If you're new to coding, you may want to look at XSLTs, although the XSLT 'language' can be a bit tricky for complex problems, I suspect it can handle yours with minimal effort and would only take a few lines of XSLT 'code' and a few lines of which ever language you want to use to run the XSLT (e.g. Java, C#, VB etc).